# Difference between urxvt -e and xterm -e

Tags: mutt, xterm, urxvt

Create an executable file `file1` as follows:

```
cat > file1 <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
mutt -e "push '<'"
EOF
chmod +x file1
```

Running `./file1` in an existing terminal executes mutt and select the first message (this is what the command `<` does).
Running `xterm -e ./file1` opens xterm, runs mutt and selects the first message. However, running `urxvt -e ./file` opens urxvt, runs mutt but selects the *last* message (the default in the absence of the "push '<'" directive).

Any ideas about why `urxvt -e ./file1` behaves in this specific way?

---

Further clues:

With the following file, `xterm -e ./file2` and `urxvt -e ./file2` both result in the intended behavior.

```
cat > file2 <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
echo foo
sleep 1
mutt -e "push '<'"
EOF
chmod +x file2
```

The following file still results in the intended behavior with xterm, but I've seen `urxvt -e ./file3` result in both behaviors nondeterministically.

```
cat > file3 <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
echo              
mutt -e "push '<'" 
EOF
chmod +x file3
```

Testing with `gnome-terminal` yields the same behavior as `xterm`, so it seems like something is wrong with `urxvt`, but I was not able to reproduce such differences in behavior with anything other than mutt. What the hell is going on here?